# for loop questions python matching excel

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

I am trying to go through an entire row of cells and compare it to the row of cells on another excel sheet. i have figured it out so that it reads from the sheet, but there must be something wrong with my for loops and if statements. what i am doing is assigning the first cell and then comparing it to the first cell in the other sheet. if they are equal i want it to write a ' ' in a different sheet, at the point of that row in the first sheet. if they aren't the same, i want to see if the first 6 digits are the same, and if they are... i want to write "CHECK" on that cell on the first sheet. i want to keep going down the cells in the second sheet, and until that is all checked, move on to the next cell in the first sheet and start over.

what is wrong with my code here? it is outputting the wrong outputs into the excel sheet.

thank you.

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
     cell = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))

         for row in range(windc_sheet.nrows):

             windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(row, 0));

             if cell == windcell:
                outputsheet.write(row, 1, ' ')
             else:
                sixdig = cell[0:6]
                sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
                if sixdig == sixdigwind:
                    outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
         else:
             continue;


 else:
     continue


error output onto excel:        wanted output:

check                            check
check              
check 
check                            check 
check
```

two sheets being compared:

```
 123456-01            123455-01
 124445               123336-55
 123454-99            123456-02
 123455-03            133377-66
 1277                 199227-22
```

Comment: Could you please include the erroneous output along with expected output

Comment: done @Osssan :)

Answer (score 0):

Second iteration is the one that is making the error. Just try this:

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = str(sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    windcell = str(windc_sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
    if cell == windcell:
       outputsheet.write(row, 1, ' ')
    else:
       sixdig = cell[0:6]
       sixdigwind = windcell[0:6]
       if sixdig == sixdigwind:
           outputsheet.write(row, 1, 'Check')
```

Comment: hi @Boris. I need it to go through all of the rows in the other sheet as well. i believe there needs to be two for loops

Comment: Hi @Emily. You are going trough both of them. The variable **row** is just an integer that you are using to indicate which row are you accessing and comparing in two sheets.

Comment: hi @Boris. isn't it going through it row by row, though? or is it checking first cell and comparing it to everything... then next cell and comparing it to everything. etc

Comment: that's why i would think what I have is fine. thanks